# Assisted Service Module (ASM) for Spartacus set up

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to set up the ASM on our headless SAP Commerce project (version 1905.12).
This documentation: [ASM in Spartacus](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/asm/)

states that 2 extensions are needed: assistedservicewebservices Extension and assistedservicestorefront AddOn. However, there is no storefront in our project to connect the storefront addon to.

I've tried adding these extensions and their dependecies to localextensions.properties and installing the assistedservicestorefront AddOn by connecting it to our custom webservices extension, which failed. It was always reporting:

> GUIDCookieStrategy cannot be resolved to a type.

Even though all dependencies are there.
By dependencies, I mean the ones from this picture:
[ASM dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKPbP.png)

Now, for me, it makes no sense to use any storefront extensions on the back-end, when our storefront is on Spartacus.

**My question is:**
What do you need in order to set up ASM on SAP Commerce Cloud when Spartacus storefront is used? Which extensions/other dependencies or configurations?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be honest, I have not tried this specific configuration myself ... all of my Spartacus setups have had a storefront alongside as well for demo & side-by-side comparison ...

However in principal what you say should be correct & you cannot use a storefront addon as an occ addon with your webservices extension (addons do rely to an extent on the structure within the main extension & that differs between yacceleratorstorefront vs ycommercewebservices).

However, on reviewing the code I have noticed that the assistedservicesstorefront does includes a couple of items in the -items.xml & -spring.xml that are usable as a normal extension - these are component and restriction types.  On that basis it may be the recommendation means to include it as a standard extension, without necessarily using it as an addon.

Comment: Thank you. This did enable me to access the asm.

Comment: I did manage to access the view. However, the process flow after asagent log in is off. Customer is never emulated. I get a bunch of unauthorized errors due to invoking security filters in our custom webservices extensions, and not the ones defined in assistedservicewebservices-web-spring.xml. Can this really work without a storefront extension (I think it should, but...) and if so, how? :(